# Cumulative monthly sum with reset to zero at the beginning of each new month in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, cumulative-sum

I have a pandas dataframe with daily data

```
Date          Value
2020-01-01    1780.2
2020-01-02    1783.3
2020-01-05    1781.5
...
2020-02-01    1816.0
2020-02-02    1810.4
...
```

There is not always a value for every day of the month, so some days could be missing, therefore the timedelta is not always 1 day.

What I want to do is simply take a cumulative sum within every month, but then reset the sum to zero at the beginning of the next month, so the result would look like below

```
Date          Value    Cumulative Value
2020-01-01    1780.2   1780.2
2020-01-02    1783.3   3563.5
2020-01-05    1781.5   5345.0
...
2020-02-01    1816.0   1816.0
2020-02-02    1810.4   3626.4
...
```

I have found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42691528/4139143) which explains how to get a cumulative sum by month. But what I need is to reset the cumulative sum to zero at the beginning of each month. How can I do this?

Comment: `groupby` by month then `sum` each group

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution if multiple years is grouping by month periods by [`Series.dt.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html):

```
df['Cumulative Value'] = df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.to_period('m'))['Value'].cumsum()
```

Solution if ony one year is possible use [`Series.dt.month`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.month.html):

```
df['Cumulative Value'] = df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.month)['Value'].cumsum()
```

Also cumulative sum by default reset to `0`, so not necessary add code for this.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that *Date* column is of *datetime* type. If not, convert it.

As I understand, you want grouping not solely by month (e.g. put together
data from all years in January, February and so on (like in 2 other
answers)), but the grouping should be by **year and month** (you want
to start form *0* **at the beginning of the next month**).

To compute your new column this way, run:

```
df['Cumulative Value'] = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='M')).Value.cumsum()
```

The result, for your data sample is:

```
        Date   Value  Cumulative Value
0 2020-01-01  1780.2            1780.2
1 2020-01-02  1783.3            3563.5
2 2020-01-05  1781.5            5345.0
3 2020-02-01  1816.0            1816.0
4 2020-02-02  1810.4            3626.4
```

Answer (score 0):

`groupy()` an extracted month, `transform('cumsum')`

```
 df['Cumulative Value']=df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df.Date).dt.month).transform('cumsum')



     Date         Value        Cumulative Value
0  2020-01-01  1780.2            1780.2
1  2020-01-02  1783.3            3563.5
2  2020-01-05  1781.5            5345.0
3  2020-02-01  1816.0            1816.0
4  2020-02-02  1810.4            3626.4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
start='2020-01-01' 
end='2020-12-31'
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": pd.date_range(start, end)})
df['qty']=1
df = df.groupby('Date').qty.sum()
print(df.head())
df=df.groupby(df.index.month).cumsum().reset_index()
print(df.head(45))
```

Output:

```
Date
2020-01-01    1
2020-01-02    1
2020-01-03    1
2020-01-04    1
2020-01-05    1
Name: qty, dtype: int64
         Date  qty
0  2020-01-01    1
1  2020-01-02    2
2  2020-01-03    3
3  2020-01-04    4
4  2020-01-05    5
5  2020-01-06    6
6  2020-01-07    7
7  2020-01-08    8
8  2020-01-09    9
9  2020-01-10   10
10 2020-01-11   11
11 2020-01-12   12
12 2020-01-13   13
13 2020-01-14   14
14 2020-01-15   15
15 2020-01-16   16
16 2020-01-17   17
17 2020-01-18   18
18 2020-01-19   19
19 2020-01-20   20
20 2020-01-21   21
21 2020-01-22   22
22 2020-01-23   23
23 2020-01-24   24
24 2020-01-25   25
25 2020-01-26   26
26 2020-01-27   27
27 2020-01-28   28
28 2020-01-29   29
29 2020-01-30   30
30 2020-01-31   31
31 2020-02-01    1
32 2020-02-02    2
33 2020-02-03    3
34 2020-02-04    4
35 2020-02-05    5
36 2020-02-06    6
37 2020-02-07    7
38 2020-02-08    8
39 2020-02-09    9
40 2020-02-10   10
41 2020-02-11   11
42 2020-02-12   12
43 2020-02-13   13
44 2020-02-14   14
```