# Change column values in Pandas DataFrame with cumsum that resets yearly back to daily/monthly values

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe df1 shown below. Its a cumulative sum which resets every year.

```
values  values1 values2
date            
2010-01-01  1   1   4
2010-02-01  3   2   8
2010-03-01  3   3   10
2010-04-01  5   4   13
2010-05-01  9   5   14
2010-06-01  12  5   15
2010-07-01  15  7   17
2010-08-01  16  11  18
2010-09-01  16  13  20
2010-10-01  18  13  20
2010-11-01  22  13  21
2010-12-01  26  15  21
2011-01-01  2   0   0
2011-02-01  5   2   4
2011-03-01  6   4   4
2011-04-01  6   6   6
2011-05-01  10  10  8
2011-06-01  13  10  9
2011-07-01  14  13  9
2011-08-01  15  16  11
2011-09-01  17  19  13
2011-10-01  17  19  16
2011-11-01  20  22  16
2011-12-01  22  23  19
```

I am trying to get dataframe df2 as follows, which is just the monthly data without any cumsum whatsover.

```
    test    test1   test2
date            
2010-01-01  1   1   4
2010-02-01  2   1   4
2010-03-01  0   1   2
2010-04-01  2   1   3
2010-05-01  4   1   1
2010-06-01  3   0   1
2010-07-01  3   2   2
2010-08-01  1   4   1
2010-09-01  0   2   2
2010-10-01  2   0   0
2010-11-01  4   0   1
2010-12-01  4   2   0
2011-01-01  2   0   0
2011-02-01  3   2   4
2011-03-01  1   2   0
2011-04-01  0   2   2
2011-05-01  4   4   2
2011-06-01  3   0   1
2011-07-01  1   3   0
2011-08-01  1   3   2
2011-09-01  2   3   2
2011-10-01  0   0   3
2011-11-01  3   3   0
2011-12-01  2   1   3
```

The following is the code to generate df1 and df2. I'm trying to reverse the groupby and cumsum process. I followed the groupby and cumsum shown here [Cumulative monthly sum with reset to zero at the beginning of each new month in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63934767/cumulative-monthly-sum-with-reset-to-zero-at-the-beginning-of-each-new-month-in)

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

date_today = datetime.now()
ndays=pd.date_range(start='2010', end='2012', freq='M').shape[0]
test_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'date': pd.date_range(start='2010', end='2012', freq='M').strftime('%Y-%m'), 
    'test': pd.Series(np.random.randint(5,size=ndays)),
    'test1': pd.Series(np.random.randint(5,size=ndays)),
    'test2': pd.Series(np.random.randint(5,size=ndays))
    }
)
test_df = test_df.set_index('date')
test_df.index = pd.to_datetime(test_df.index)
test_df[['values','values1','values2']] = test_df.groupby(test_df.index.year)[['test','test1','test2']].cumsum()

df1 = pd.DataFrame(test_df[['values','values1','values2']])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(test_df[['test','test1','test2']])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `diff` after `resample`:

```
df.resample('Y')[['values', 'values1', 'values2']].\
         diff().fillna(df[['values', 'values1', 'values2']])
```

Comment: Wow thanks for that. Can I know what .\ means? I have not seen that syntax before.

Comment: @hengjuice that's simply a line break :)

Comment: It is just an escape character I used so that I can continue the code in the new line