# Count and cumsum per month in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a pandas DataFrame with two columns: `id` and `processing_date`.

The latter being the date an item (id) was processed.

```py
import pandas as pd
# df
  id  processed_date
 324      2016-07-08
A550      2016-07-09
  79      2016-08-10
C295      2016-08-10
 413      2016-08-11
...
 111      2021-11-08 
 709      2021-11-08
```

I want to plot both a graph that shows the amount of items that were processed each months and a cumulative graph "over the months". As I have 5 years and 4 months of data, I must have 64 entries and 64 data points to plot as a bar or line plot.

This is what I get from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42691405/cumulative-sum-by-date-month) but it's not working as expected:

```py
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['processed_date']) # needed by the nature of the data
df.set_index('date')

df = df.groupby('date')['id'].count() # <- this will stack items per day
df = df.groupby(df.index.month)['id'].count() # <- this will stack items per 12 months, but I have 5 years and 4 months of data, hence 64 different months, not 12.
```

How could I achieve that?

Ideal output:

```py
# df
  nb_items_processed  cum_sum year_month
                   2        2    2016-07
                   3        5    2016-08
...
                   2      xxx    2021-11
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start out with `groupby().size()` for the monthly count, then cumsum without groupby:

```
out = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='processed_date', freq='M')).size().reset_index(name='nb_items_processed')

out['cum_sum'] = out['nb_items_processed'].cumsum()
```

Comment: key must be `date` otherwise this error could be raised:
`TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'` (the original date is of dtype 'object' in my case, hence the transform to a true datetime index).

Comment: If you already set (datetime) date as your index, then you can remove the key argument.